# retrieve the identity value in Linq transaction

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, transactions

I'm trying to do the following transaction using Linq to sql.

but the ***id*** Field is not retrieved so an exception occurs

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

so what to do?

my code:

```
System.Data.Common.DbTransaction transaction = null;
            DBDataContext db = new DBDataContext();
            db.Connection.Open();
            transaction = db.Connection.BeginTransaction();
            db.Transaction = transaction;

            Table1 = new Table1();
            obj.objName = "some name";
            db.Table1s.InsertOnSubmit(obj);

            Table2 obj_info = new Table2();
            obj_info.Info = "some info";
            obj_info.Id = obj.Id;
            db.Table2s.InsertOnSubmit(obj_info);
            try
            {
                db.SubmitChanges();
                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
            finally
            {
                transaction.Dispose();
                db.Dispose();
            }
```

Edit:maybe i the code wasn't clear enough 
the **obj** variable has the primary key Id so obj.Id is the auto-generated identity 
and i need to insert it into obj_info.Id which is foreign key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like i need to use SubmitChanges after evert insert

```
        System.Data.Common.DbTransaction transaction = null;
        DBDataContext db = new DBDataContext();
        db.Connection.Open();
        transaction = db.Connection.BeginTransaction();
        db.Transaction = transaction;

        Table1 = new Table1();
        obj.objName = "some name";
        db.Table1s.InsertOnSubmit(obj);
        db.SubmitChanges();

        Table2 obj_info = new Table2();
        obj_info.Info = "some info";
        obj_info.Id = obj.Id;
        db.Table2s.InsertOnSubmit(obj_info);
        db.SubmitChanges();
        try
        {
            db.SubmitChanges();
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
        finally
        {
            transaction.Dispose();
            db.Dispose();
        }
```

I'm not totally sure about this but it worked

if any one can confirm it please tell me

Answer (score 1):

The clue should be on the name **InsertOnSubmit**. Your transaction is not submitted and hence does not have an id when you try to assign it.

I'm not clear on the exact relationship between this tables, but if you had a table called obj_info which had a column called objID which was used to store id of the related record in the obj table, then in your c# classes you would expect to have two properties like

```
public Obj obj;
public int objID;
```

If that is the case you could then use

```
 obj_info.obj = obj;
```

instead of

```
 obj_info.objID = obj.id
```

If your tables are not related, then you need to submit obj first before you can access the id.

Comment: my tables are related as you said but after trying it i still have the same exception

Answer (score 0):

```
 1. your obj_info.id has a not null value
 2. your table2 doesn't have an incremental value
the mistake came from one of those points
```

Comment: the value been inserted to the obj_info.id is 0 which mean the identity is not retrieved 
table2 does not have incremental value off course because it should get the id form table1
thanks anyway

Comment: the error message indicate that you don't have a good obj_info.Id (it doesn't match with obj.id of table1 if obj.id is primary key and obj_info.id is FK°

Comment: You can have a simple test set a hard value in obj_info.id that match with an existing obj.id value that is obj_info.id =1

Comment: I mentioned what you're saying in my last edit 
obj.id is pk obj_info.id is fk

Comment: have you try my test? setting a hard value?